# Using wildcard in informix stored procedure parameters

Tags: sql, informix

I have an ibm informix stored procedure below. I can get result of this procedure by calling in squirrel. Here is the question comes, result might be giant that can contain unnecessary over 20 columns and hundred rows.
Therefore, I need to use input parameter (calling address parameter in procedure) instead of first NULL parameter below that must contains wildcard like "052%" to specific result. When I tried to use wildcard, it does return empty result.

calling with null value

```
CALL sp_ccdr('2012-08-07 00:00:00.000', 
        '2012-08-08 00:00:00.000',  
        '0', NULL, NULL,NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
         NULL, '0','0',NULL,NULL,'f')
```

calling with wildcard

```
CALL sp_ccdr('2012-08-07 00:00:00.000', 
        '2012-08-08 00:00:00.000',  
        '0', "052%", NULL,NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
         NULL, '0','0',NULL,NULL,'f')
```

and how can i select some columns from result-set ?

```
select col1 from (CALL sp_ccdr('2012-08-07 00:00:00.000', 
        '2012-08-08 00:00:00.000',  
        '0', "052%", NULL,NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
         NULL, '0','0',NULL,NULL,'f'))
```

it does not work. I get a syntax error.

Comment: Is the stored procedure written to support filtering in this manner? We'll need to see the SPL code.

Comment: Unfortunately, the SPL code does not make sense for me. Is it t-sql or pl/sql using by informix ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, Informix does not support CALL.  Some APIs might convert the CALL into EXECUTE PROCEDURE for you, but that's not what you need to do in the last example.

```
SELECT col1
  FROM TABLE(MULTISET(sp_ccdr('2012-08-07 00:00:00.000', '2012-08-08 00:00:00.000',  
                              '0', "052%", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
                              NULL, '0', '0', NULL, NULL, 'f')));
```

This at least stands a chance of working; I've not run the syntax past the DBMS so there could be a bug in it.

Comment: I run this code on the squirrel editor to past DBMS. But there must be some bugs so syntax error appears.